# How to use part of a disk for Storage Spaces?

Tags: windows-10, diskmanagement, storage-spaces

I want to use Storage Spaces to create mirrored volumes. However, my disks are large and I do not wish to fill the entire disks with the Storage Spaces volumes.

Unfortunately, the GUI only appears to accept entire disks for inclusion into Storage Spaces. How do I only use part of a disk for Storage Spaces, retaining the ability to use normal partitions on the remaining part?

I am using latest version of Windows 10 Enterprise (Creators Update).

Comment: Start by reading the documentation. Then realize very quickly that no, it is not supported. It also makes no sense - why would you NOT use the whole discs when you can then assign logical volumes as wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: You can't do that. If you really want to do that you have to use sort of a storage virtualization stack on top of your disks. Something like HPE VSA will use your existing partitioning and allow to expose PART of your storage pool to external consumers.

Comment: I agree with this statement. Also, I want to share the links that you mentioned: https://saas.hpe.com/en-us/try  By the way, when it comes to virtualization software you should take a look on:
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free it might be helpful.